# Pandas dataframe group-by a modified index

Tags: python, pandas

I have following panda data-frame and I am trying to group it by Index1 column values after extracting the right hand side of the dash sign, i.e., z and y.

```
Index1  Index2  Value
 a-z    1       10
 a-z    2       10
 a-z    1       4
 c-z    2       5
 c-z    1       9
 c-z    2       6
 a-z    1       6
 a-y    2       7
 b-y    1       8
 b-y    2       2
 c-y    1       9
 c-y    2       4
```

So the final result after using group-by sum should be something like this:

```
Index1  Index2  Value
z       1       29
z       2       21
y       1       17
y       2       13
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: df.groupby([df.get_level_values(0).str.slice(start=2),df.get_level_values(1)]).sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.groupby([df['Index1'].str[-1], df['Index2']])['Value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Index1   Index2  Value
0    y        1      17
1    y        2      13
2    z        1      29
3    z        2      21
```

Comment: @AlexMan, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).